# Why doesn't Android Facebook interface work with Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, facebook-android-sdk, fragmentpageradapter

I'm switching some Android **Facebook** code from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`.  Prior to the switch everything worked fine, but now the `onComplete()` callback is not being executed.

Does the Facebook code not work with **Fragments**, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the original code (in a `SherlockActivity`):

```
if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
    mFacebook.authorize(MyActivity.this, permissions, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) { ... }    // CALLED AS EXPECTED
    }
}
```

And here's the new code (in a SherlockFragment):

```
if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
    mFacebook.authorize(getActivity(), permissions, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) { ... }    // DOES NOT GET CALLED
    }
}
```

Both the Activity and the Fragment include the same onActivityResult() as required by Facebook:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835094/does-the-facebook-sdk-only-work-with-activities), where the accepted answer is to change the `Fragment` to a `FragmentActivity`.  But I don't see how this helps, as then it's no longer a `Fragment` (which I need for other reasons).  Suggestions?

EDIT 2: I rolled my own solution.  See below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I could determine, the Facebook auth API does not support **Fragments**.  Specifically, the `onComplete()` callback from the Facebook `authorize()` call works with **Activities**, but not with **Fragments**.

So I put together a simple workaround for **Fragments**.  The solution depends on the fact that `onActivityResult()` is also called in the parent **Activity** when the `authorize()` call completes, so you can use it to set up a separate *callback* mechanism for the **Fragment**.

First, set up a variable in the parent **Activity** to carry the target **Fragment's** name, say

```
TargetFragment mTargetFragment;
```

You can initialize it when the Fragment is first instantiated like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    String fragmentSimpleName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();

    if (fragmentSimpleName.equals("TargetFragment"))
        mTargetFragment = (TargetFragment)fragment;        
}
```

Then add a couple of lines to the onActivityResult() function:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (mTargetFragment != null)       
        mTargetFragment.myCallBack(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Now you can just mimic the code you would ordinarily put in the onComplete() callback in the new myCallBack() function:

```
public void myCallBack(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // other code from your onComplete() function ...
}
```

I hope this can help someone else.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi
I'm trying this solution but I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException on facebook.authorizeCallback in myCallback function.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if authorizeCallback() actually does a network transaction, but if so, you'll need to move it out of any user-facing Activity (using something like an AsyncTask).  This is because Android has a strict mode that prevents user facing threads from executing network transactions.  For a quick development workaround, you can put the following two lines in your Activity's onCreate() call: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);   Be sure to remove the workaround and fix before production.  Good luck!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943392/why-doesnt-android-facebook-interface-work-with-fragments/10964421#comment17300713_10964421

Comment: This worked for me. My Fragment that was implementing the Facebook DialogListener. During the Facebook authorize() call, the Fragment and parent Activity were being destroyed. Upon returning from the authorize() call, the Activity/Fragment were recreated, but the old Fragment got the callbacks. With it no longer attached to an Activity, UI related actions could take place without it errors.

So I switched up the code to have the Activity be the DialogListener. When a callback occurs, I have the Activity lookup the current Fragment and delegate the calls to it. Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I reported my original problem to Facebook as a bug, and they reported it fixed as of Oct 11.  See http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/430907140266154.  I have yet to go back and take out my workaround, but will do!

Comment: have same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059269/why-the-facebook-sharing-is-not-working-with-fragments

Answer (score 5):

I have downloaded the latest version of Facebook SDK and I have the same problem, the solution of [gcl1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322527/gcl1) works fine but I have to do more things on activity result so I have made this on the parent activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (mTargetFragment != null) {
        mTargetFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK don't works with Fragment, but works with FragmentActivity. 
So you need:

1. Catch the FB login info in onActivityResult() in your parent FragmentActivity.
2. Pass activity results to your child Fragment

example:

1.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity(){


/* catch FACEBOOK login info and call onFBLoginActivityResult() to pass it to FacebookFrragment*/
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
       FacebookFragment fbfragment= (FacebookFragment ) fm.findFragmentByTag("facebookfragment");
       selectPKEConfigFragment.onFBLoginActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

2.

```
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment{

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ........... 

         // start Facebook Login

                    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                      // callback when session changes state
                      @Override
                      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {
                          // make request to the /me API
                          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                              if (user != null) {
                               // TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                               // welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                                  Log.i(TAG,"User: " + user.getName());
                              }
                              else  Log.i(TAG,"User: null");
                            }
                          });
                        }
                        else Log.i(TAG,"session closed");
                      }


                    });

            }

        /*
         * replace onActivityResult
         */
        public void onFBLoginActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
             Log.i(TAG,"Activity result SelectPKEConfig");
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you look at [Facebook Docs for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=tr_TR) you'll see the login example uses fragment in it.

There is LoginButton widget that Facebook SDK provides and it has a method called **setFragment** and you pass the target fragment that you want to use login functionality with.

## In your fragment layout

Add the login button that Facebook SDK provides.

```
        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

## In your fragment

Create **UiLifecycleHelper** and **StatusCallback** objects in your fragment.

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

Add a method to handle the user state changes.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("LoginFragment", "Logged in...");
        Log.i("LoginFragment", session.getAccessToken());
        doAnythingWithTheFacebookToken(session.getAccessToken());
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // this part is called when user login fails
        Log.i("LoginFragment", "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Override the fragment lifecycle methods

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflate your fragment view

    facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
    facebookLoginButton.setFragment(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

## Result

Normally you'd need to override **onActivityResult** in your activity but calling **setFragment()** on Facebook Login Button allows your fragment to receive the result in its own **onActivityResult**.

If you want to use a different button (your own button for example):

- hide the facebookLoginButton in layout
- call **performClick()** on facebookLoginButton inside the onclick listener of your actual button

That's it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059269/why-the-facebook-sharing-is-not-working-with-fragments

Comment: This answer should be accepted worldwide. Thanks @eluleci setFragment() work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to configure onActivityResult inside main activity of fragment class and inside fragment to.
Just put below code inside main activity that contains your fragment and do rest of facebook sdk code inside fragment ...its so simple.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(ChatScreen.this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
    }
```