# LogIn with Facebook SDK 3.5 on Android

Tags: android, facebook

So I am developing an application that use Facebook LogIn  then get User Profile Data right after login successfully. However I am facing a problem with using facebook SDK in my Fragment (not FragmentActivity). When I first click LogIn Button it pops up the windows to enter Username and Password, after the LogIn it returns me back to my fragment with the button is still "Log In with Facebook", not "Log Out" and I can't get the data. It seems to be caused by the fact that it didn't call onActivityResult. I have searched quite a lot and come accross this [Why doesn't Android Facebook interface work with Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943392/why-doesnt-android-facebook-interface-work-with-fragments/10964421#comment17300713_10964421) and https://github.com/dinocore1/facebook-android-sdk but I can't make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you registered the key hash in Facebook app dashboard?

Comment: Yes I have, in another activity, I am able to share post on wall by using Facebook.dialog. The flow in that activity is a little bit different though. When the user click on the button it will call facebook dialog, if user hasn't logged in yet, it will automatically ask the user to log in the share the post. In this activity I am asking, I need the user to log in first then get the profile data later.

Comment: If you're using the LoginButton in your fragment, did you call loginButton.setFragment(yourFragmentInstance), and also override the onActivityResult method in your Fragment class?

Comment: sorry for replying this late. I was so busy on other stuff. Thanks for you comment, my code is working now :)